# Filtering open dialog according pre-defined filename

Tags: delphi, filter, fileopendialog

1. Question number 1:
   I want to filter open dialog that will only display certain file name. The file name is given on TEdit box. This is my code, but it still show the whole file in the directory.

   procedure TForm1.ButtonLoad(Sender: TObject);

   ```
   var
     openDialog: TOpenDialog; 
     i: Integer;
   begin
    TFBusy(sender);
     openDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(self);
     openDialog.Title := 'Browsing desired file, Browse for '+ TEdit1.Text;
     openDialog.InitialDir := strMyDoc;
     openDialog.FileName := TEdit1.Text;
     openDialog.Filter := 'All file extension|*.*';
     try
       if not openDialog.Execute then
       begin
   mem0.lines.add('Browse file to load was cancelled');
       end;
     finally

     for i := 0 to openDialog.Files.Count - 1 do
         //i do here with the file

     end;
     openDialog.Free;
     TFReady(sender);
   end;
   ```

Although the file name on open dialog display correctly, but it's still displays the whole files inside directory.

Question number 2:

Can I filter file with certain prefix?
E.g; My file name is FLOWER-3320, FLOWER-2230, and so on. SO i want to filter open dialog that will only display any file with prefix name FLOWER- (ignore file extension)

Best Wishes,
Bee.

Comment: If you want the dialog to show a single filename, use that filename as your filter. The UI of this program doesn't sound ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows all files because you explicitly told it so:

```
openDialog.Filter := 'All file extension|*.*';
```

Setting the filename alone does not filter the open dialog.

You can use a filter like this:

```
openDialog.Filter := 'Flower Files|FLOWER-*.*';
```

to display all files with prefix "FLOWER-". If you want to filter all but one specific filename, just leave out the wildcard in the first part of the filter:

```
openDialog.Filter := 'Flower-2230 File|FLOWER-2230.*';
```

But (as David points out in his comment) why have an open dialog when you restrict the selection to a single file?

Comment: Thank's. It's working. Can i filter only exact file name as given on tedit box without paying attention to the file extension?

Comment: @Bianca What exactly do you mean, and can't you work it out your self?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the messy question. The problem is: my files (plain files, encrypted), some of them do not have any file extension. So, to get it filtering just like what i desired, is by file name filter and prefix. It is not single file anyway. The edit box is dynamic according to user input.

Comment: So leave the extension out then. I don't understand why you are struggling still

Comment: `openDialog.Filter := Edit1.Text + '|*FLOWER-*.*' ;`

is not showing the file exactly as on Edit box, it shows whole file with FLOWER-

Comment: @Bianca I do not understand. Tell us precisely, verbatim, what the problem is. Exact name of file. Exact content of edit box. Precisely the behaviour you need.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. 
`openDialog.Filter := Edit1.Text + '|FLOWER-*.*|Substitude with other FLOWER|*FLOWER-*.*' ;`

You guys are awesome! Thank you so much.. <3